# simplify expectation definition Hidden Markov Model

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, bayesian-network

I am reading Rabiner's paper entitled "A tutorial on hidden markov models and selected applications in speech recognition". 
There is a very simple example where he simplifies the calculation of an expectation that I don't follow, I assume that this is basic (which worries me), I just can't seem to reach it :(

$$
E[d]=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d·P(d)
\\
E[d]=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d·(a)^{d-1}(1-a)
\\
E[d]=\frac{1}{1-a}
$$

In particular this is equation `6a` in the paper. And here I ommited subindices of `a` and `P`, cause they are not needed. I just want to find the way he simplifies it.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a hint write
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} a^d & = & \frac{1}{1 - a}
\end{eqnarray*}
Take derivatives on both sides with respect to $a$ (I will not say rigorously why it is allowed
here)
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} da^{d - 1} & = & \frac{1}{\left( 1 - a \right)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Multiply by $\left( 1 - a \right)$ on both sides to conclude $$E[d]=\frac{1}{1-a}$$

Comment: Great! I guess I wouldn't have figured it out myself. Because I was trying to reach the goal $$ \frac{1}{1-a} $$ without explicitly writing it down in my `=` sign. How would you reach that goal without knowing it explicitly? thanks!

Comment: @vint-i-vuit Knowing that $1/(1-a)$ is the normalizing constant of the distribution of $d$ is essential here (This is what makes the sum equal to one). It is nothing more than the sum of a geometric progression!

Comment: @vint-i-vuit But still, there might be other ways to prove the result.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation!